# Make all folders in folder and subfolders lowercase

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to do this via CMD or powershell? I don't want to lowercase the files. Just the foldernames.

Comment: What did you try? Any code to show? If you want batch/powershell you should apply the relevant tags. And a search on [SO] finds (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+rename+lowercase+uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b/s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%m IN (
  'dir /b /L /ad "%%~dpa" '
  ) DO (
  IF /i "%%~nxa" equ "%%~nxm" IF "%%~nxa" neq "%%~nxm" ECHO(ren "%%a" "%%~nxm"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

perform a directory scan for directorynames in basic form. With the directories found in `%%a`, scan the parent directory in `%%~dpa` for names in basic form in lower case (`/L`).

If the name+extension matches in case-insensitive mode but not as a direct comparison, then the name is not in lower-case, so rename it.

---

Given comments,

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

IF "%sourcedir%"=="." SET "sourcedir=%cd%"
:genrnddir
SET /a tempdir=%RANDOM%
IF EXIST %tempdir% GOTO genrnddir
MD "%tempdir%"&PUSHD "%tempdir%"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b/s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%m IN (
  'dir /b /l /ad "%%~dpa" '
  ) DO (
  IF /i "%%~nxa" equ "%%~nxm" IF "%%~nxa" neq "%%~nxm" ECHO(ren "%%a" "%%~nxm"
 )
)
POPD
RD "%tempdir%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Set `sourcedir` to current directoryname if it's specified as "here"

Create and change to a temporary directory

execute original procedure, where the current directory is empty, hence the "if in current directory" problem is avoided.

go back to original directory and clean up.

Comment: Actually you should be able to use use the /L option in the first FOR command and get rid of the second for command and go straight to the rename.  If the directory is already named in upper case the rename command does not care if the folder name is upper or lower when you issue the rename command.  If it is UPPER and you do a `ren upper upper` it handles it just fine.  So you can basically rename it regardless of it being upper or lower.

Comment: @Squashman: Good thinking. Unfortunately, it does not work. `FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ( 'dir /b /s /L /ad "%sourcedir%\*" ' ) DO ECHO(ren "%%a" "%%~nxa"` - which can all be on one line - shows a rename with the target name in CaMeLcAsE on my machine (Win10). Same if you use `for/f` on `"%%~a"` or `"%%~nxa"` - thos upper-case characters are still there...And yes, this surprises me. Such a good idea, but sorry - that little boat's got a wee hole in it...

Comment: Very odd because I tested it on Windows 10 last night before I posted my comment.

Comment: @Squashman - Two loops are required because a single loop will have the full path within `%%a`, so `%%~nxa` will revert to the original case - the lowercase effect from `DIR /L` will be lost.

Comment: @Magoo - Your use of `%%~nxm` leads to a bug if any `%%m` happens to match a file or folder name within the current directory. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JREN.BAT - A regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). JREN.BAT is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

The regular expression capabilities are not even needed for this task, the `/L` option will convert file or folder names to lower case. So the find replace strings can simply be empty strings. I think it is slightly faster if the search uses the begin line anchor `"^"`.

The following line will recursively rename all folders within the current directory to lowercase:

```
jren "^" "" /s /d /l
```

If you want to rename folders in a different folder, then simply add the `/P` option.

```
jren "^" "" /s /d /l /p "c:\yourRootPath"
```

Since JREN is itself a batch script, you must use `CALL JREN` if you put the command within another batch script.

Magoo has a pure batch script that mostly works, but it is not reliable as currently written. The problem is that the modifiers in `%%~nxm` will revert to the current case found on disk if a file or folder with the same name (ignoring case) exists in the current directory. That bug can be fixed by using `%%m` instead of `%%~nxm`.

But the script is also inefficient in that it iterates a Cartesian product - If there are 5 folders in folder A, then the 5 folders are iterated 5 times.

Here is how I would write the pure batch solution:

```
@echo off
for /d /r "rootPath" %%A in (.) do (
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%B in ('dir /b /ad /l "%%A"') do (
    ren "%%A\%%B" "%%B"
  )
)
```

The above will rename all folders, even those that are already lowercase. But that really shouldn't be a problem to rename a folder to itself.

If you really want to only rename folders that contain at least one uppercase character using pure batch, then I would use the following:

```
@echo off
for /d /r "rootPath" %%A in (*) do (
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%B in ('dir /b /ad /l "%%A?"') do (
    if /i "%%~nxA" equ "%%B" if "%%~nxA" neq "%%B" echo ren "%%A" "%%B"
  )
)
```

The `?` in the DIR command within the 2nd FOR loop is critical - the wildcard ensures that the correct folder is listed, with minimal chance of additional unwanted folders being listed. Because there is a chance for more than one folder being listed, the case insensitive IF statement is required to make sure we rename the correct folder.